# I will call somebody else, not neither him nor you

Tags: negation, multiple-negation, neither-nor

I have a sentence

***I will call neither you nor him***

I guess it means

***I won't call neither you nor him***

Out of it it's not clear whether I will call anyone at all but I want to say that I will call but among the people I will call there will be neither you nor him. Can I say it like

***I will call somebody else, NOT neither you nor him***

or should it be like

***I will call somebody else, neither you nor him***

I am worried **NOT neither you nor him** = 2 negations which is a bad grammar.

Answer (score 1):

> I will call neither you nor him
> I guess it means
> I won't call neither you nor him

No, it doesn’t mean that.

**Either...or** = this one or that one.

**Neither...nor** = not this one and not that one.

**Either...or** is used to make a choice between two or more options, but we are not sure that which one is definite.

**Neither...nor** is used to emphasize that more than one thing is not possible.

---

> I won't call neither you nor him

We don’t use “‘neither...or” in negative constructions, but we do use “either...or” in a negative construction. This is already a negative sentence (consisting of **not**), therefore, there is no need to add a negative word (neither) here. Using two negatives usually turns the sentence into a positive one.

> I am worried NOT neither you nor him = 2 negations which is a bad grammar.

Yes, you are right.